# Set of counting semaphores are not working on Mac OSX

Tags: c, macos, semaphore

I have the following code in order to test whether semaphore is working or not;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int semID;
int i = -1;
struct sembuf sem_buf;

void * spawn(void * params){

    printf("semID: %d\n", semID);
    semop(semID, &sem_buf, 1);
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    shmctl(semID, 0, IPC_RMID);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    sem_buf.sem_num = 0;
    sem_buf.sem_op = -1;
    sem_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

    semID = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 4, IPC_CREAT);
    printf("semID: %d\n", semID);
    semctl(semID, 0, SETALL);

    switch(errno){
        case EACCES:
        printf("EACCES\n");
        shmctl(semID, 0, IPC_RMID);
        //return 0;
        break;

        case EEXIST:
        printf("EEXIST\n");
        shmctl(semID, 0, IPC_RMID);
        return 0;
        break;

        case EINVAL:
        printf("EINVAL\n");
        shmctl(semID, 0, IPC_RMID);
        return 0;
        break;

        case ENOENT:
        printf("ENOENT\n");
        shmctl(semID, 0, IPC_RMID);
        return 0;
        break;

        case ENOSPC:
        printf("ENOSPC\n");
        shmctl(semID, 0, IPC_RMID);
        return 0;
        break;
    }

    pthread_t threadID;
    pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, spawn, NULL);

    sleep(1);
    printf("i is becoming 72.\n");
    i = 72;

    sem_buf.sem_num = 0;
    sem_buf.sem_op = 1;
    sem_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

    return 0;
}
```

And I have the following output when I run it as root;

```
semID: 262144
semID: 262144
i: -1
i is becoming 72.
```

So the thread is not waiting for the semaphore, but why is that so ? what is wrong with the code ?

I know that unnamed semaphores, i.e *sem_init()* and *sem_destroy()*, are not working on Mac OSX, but in here we are using *setget()* and etc.

Edit:
After changing third argument of *semop()* function, as @Someprogrammerdude suggested, it worked, but still there is a problem.While creating the semaphore, if I give zero as the second argument, it returns **EINVAL**, but I checked the manage, but none of the cause of EINVAL error is occurring.So what is the problem in this case ?

Comment: The value of `errno` is *undefined* if a call haven't failed. Don't use it unless you have actually determined that a call has failed. And also remember to actually *check* for failures.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude isn't the purpose of *errno* is determine whether there is some error or not, and if there is, what is it ?

Comment: Furthermore, what *thread* are you talking about? I see no thread or process creation.

Comment: All calls that can fail will return a special value if they fail, typically `-1`. You need to check for that and *then* use `errno` to determine what the error is. ***Read the manual pages!***

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I forgot to add it I guess but still the main process doesn't wait for the semaphore.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added the thread, but the result is the same.

Comment: By the way you use the [`semop`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semop.2.html) function wrong, and it will lead to *undefined behavior*. The third argument is not the size of the structure, but the number of structures in the array you pass to `semop`. In your case the third argument should be `1` since you only have a single `sembuf` structure. And you *really* should be adding more error checking, to see if any of the functions fail (something you don't care about now, if there's a failure you just continue as if nothing happened).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, ok after changing it it worked! :), but there is still some questions that I have.I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude By the way, right now the thread doesn't pass the semop function.